# Problem with this String constructor (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, constructor

I am trying to use the constructor

```
public String(byte[] bytes,
              Charset charset)
```

Which is detailed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).
I'm using it to convert an array of bytes to ASCII. Here is the code

```
String msg = new String(raw, "US-ASCII");
```

Unfortunately, this gives me:

```
error: unreported exception UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    String msg = new String(raw, "US-ASCII");
                 ^
```

Trying a different configuration like "String msg = new String(data, 0, data.length, "ASCII");" Dosen't work either.

Is this no longer a usable constructor, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "Is this no longer a usable constructor [...]?" that's not the problem, but next time you have this doubt, read the documentation for a version of java that is not almost 15 years old. Read the documentation for the version you're using.

Comment: Anyway, you're actually using [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.lang.String)) constructor which, as you see from the docs, throws that exception, which must be explicitly caught or re-thrown.

Comment: You are reading the documentation of the method that use a String and a Charset argument, but you use the method that takes 2 String arguments. Check here for [standard charsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#US_ASCII) (java 7 doc)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This was the documentation I found when I learned about this constructor. Thank you for linking the new ones.

Comment: The problem is that you could be writing `new String(raw, "nonsensefoobar")` which obviously is non-sense. Hence Java forces you to tell it how you want to deal with the exceptional case that this encoding scheme does not exist. Either by try-catching it or by declaring `throws`. That is a super ordinary and common exception-situation, I would suggest to learn about exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte[] raw = new byte[]{};
String msg = new String(raw, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! As someone pointed out earlier I was following old documentation for my implementation.

Comment: plus 1 for proposing the constant StandardCharsets.US_ASCII where possible

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The problem is that you could be writing `new String(raw, "nonsensefoobar")` which obviously is non-sense.

Hence Java forces you to tell it how you want to deal with the exceptional case that this encoding scheme does not exist. Either by **try-catching** it or by declaring **throws**:

```
public void myMethod(){
    ...
    try {
        String msg = new String(raw, "US-ASCII");
    ...
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        ... // handle the issue
    }
    ...
}

// or

public void myMethod() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ...
    String msg = new String(raw, "US-ASCII");
    ...
}
```

That is a super ordinary and common exception-situation, I would suggest to **learn about exceptions**.

---

### Better solution

Instead of specifying the encoding scheme as string and then dealing with exceptions, you can use another overload of the constructor which takes in predefined schemes for which Java knows that they exist, so it will not bother you with exceptions:

```
String msg = new String(raw, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```